# Conditional header in CSV based on input

Tags: csv, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to feed data into elasticsearch from csv files, through logstash. 
My CSV file contains two type of input REQUEST and RESPONSE.

If the input contains "|REQUEST|" string then it  has 6 headers and 
If the input contains "|RESPONSE|" string then it has 9 headers

Sample Input Data:

```
2016-04-04 01:37:36,724|INFO|RI404013736|REQUEST|PaymentVia3DS|PT160115.02516
2016-04-04 01:38:36,724|INFO|RI888993736|RESPONSE|PaymentVia3DS|PT160115.0251|556656|4498399|XYZ9
```

Filter:

```
filter {
    if "REQUEST" in [tags] {
        csv {
            columns => ["@timestamp","LOG_TYPE","REQUEST_ID","REQUEST_TYPE","TANSACTION_TYPE","USER_IDENTIFIER"]
            separator => "|"
        }
    }

    if "RESPONSE" in [tags] {
        csv {
            columns => ["@timestamp","LOG_TYPE","REQUEST_ID","REQUEST_TYPE","TANSACTION_TYPE","USER_IDENTIFIER","CODE","ABC","ID_TYPE"]
            separator => "|"
        }
    }
```

}

Filter is not working for my data. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: You're using tags, but don't show us how they're set.  I'd be surprised if assigning to @timestamp did what you intended.  Also, what does "is not working" mean to you?

Comment: I am searching in all tags .But my problem is that i want to search "|REQUEST|" string before assigning any tag

Comment: I think you just need to  check if `REQUEST`  or `RESPONSE` are present in `message` field .  Try out  following: 
if   [message] =~ /REQUEST/ {
     csv {  ... }
} else if [message] =~ /RESPONSE/ {
     csv { .... }
}

Comment: Also  i  do not recommend you to  assign value for  `@timestamp`  filed in  your way.  Try to assign the value to `timestamp` and then parse it with `date` filter.

Comment: ok t@КириллПолищук thanks for the suggestion. i will change it in my code.

Comment: @КириллПолищук I tried : if [message] =~ /REQUEST/ { csv { ... } } else if [message] =~ /RESPONSE/ { csv { .... } }  but this solution is not working. Any other alternative?

Comment: I've tried and got  good result.  I think  your problem is that you still are using `@timestamp` field in your columns.  Change `@timestamp` to `timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a conditional across the "message" field:

```
if [message] =~ /REQUEST/ {
    ...
}
else if [message] =~ /RESPONSE/ {
    ...
}
```